# post requests in python creates an internal server error

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a post request in python, but I get an internal server error when issuing the request.
I'm trying to intercept it with a try-statement, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
import logging
import requests

logging.basicConfig(filename='python.log', filemode='w', level=logging.DEBUG)

    url = "https://redacted-url.com/my-api/check_email"
    json = {"email":request.params["email"].strip(), "list":request.params["list"]}
    headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json", "Accept": "text/plain"}

    try:
        r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=json)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        logging.error(e, exc_info=True)
```

A: I have no idea where that logging-file would be stored. Do I have to add the full server-part? What If I just use «python.log»? Where would it be stored?

B: the try/except doesn't seem to work, I still get an internal server error

C: the error definitely occurs on the line `r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=json)`. If I comment that out, the error doesn't occur.

D: Since I don't get an error that's meaningful: What am I doing wrong with that request? This is actually my main problem, but it would be nice to figure out how to log that error and how to intercept it.

Last but not least: If I run the same command from the terminal, the request is processed fine. WTH???

Comment: The internal server error comes from the server, so you would need the logs from the server to know what exactly is incorrect. What do you mean by " run the same command"? Sending the request using `curl`?

Comment: I have no idea where to find the server-log. I tried /var/log and /var/log/httpd but there's no entry for that python error. --- sending the request from the terminal using the «python»-command works flawlessly

Comment: The try/except doesn't work because there is no exception in your python code above. The error happens on the server you are posting to. That causes it to return an http response with `500` status code. You can cause that raise an exception in your python code by calling `r.raise_for_status()` after `r = requests.post(...)`, but at the moment there is no exception.

Comment: You probably need to show us a bit more of your code. Where does `request.params["email"]` come from?  Have you checked that they have the values you expect them to?

Comment: @Anentropic: Yes, I checked the params. I even sent the request using the actual email and list-variables (like r = requests.post('https://redacted-url/...', headers={'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Accept':'text/plain'}, json={'email':'me@mail.com', 'list':'the_list'}) - causes the same internal server-error

Comment: is the code above part of another web server?  i.e. you make a request to that server and then it makes a post to redacted-url.com?  Is that what you mean about it causing an Internal Server Error?  You need to be clearer about what error are happening where. Probably no one can help you without more details.

Comment: @Anentropic: when using r.raise_for_status() I still get an internal server error :(

Comment: @Anentropic: The code is called via Ajax-Request on my webserver and then in makes the request to «redacted-url.com».

Comment: @Anentropic: thanks for your help - I figured it out. I'll add an answer soon.